# HTML table from output

Tags: php, jquery

This may be very basic but I have searched for over a day trying various different things, all to no avail.

I am trying to output more than 1 row if more than 1 row exists. So far it is only showing me the last row!

My code is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT CaseID FROM Cases WHERE ClientID='".$_GET['ClientID']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $CaseID = $row['CaseID'];
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT dbUser FROM SalesUser WHERE ID='".$SalesID."';");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $SalesUser = $row['dbUser'];
}

?>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Case ID</th>
      <th>Sales User</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><? echo $CaseID; ?></td>
      <td><? echo $SalesUser; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically, I want to search for a Client ID, and have it return all cases which are for that particular client.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable against SQL injection attacks, which is very bad! I recommend reading up on "Prepared Statements", and SQL injection attacks on owasp.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store your `caseID` rows into an array and then loop over it :

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT CaseID FROM Cases WHERE ClientID='".$_GET['ClientID']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$CaseIDs = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $CaseIDs[] = $row['CaseID'];
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT dbUser FROM SalesUser WHERE ID='".$SalesID."';");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $SalesUser = $row['dbUser'];
}

?>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Case ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($CaseIDs as $CaseID) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $CaseID; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT : Same goes for `SalesID`.

EDIT 2 : With only one array :

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT Cases.CaseID, SalesUser.dbUser FROM Cases LEFT JOIN SalesUser ON [...] WHERE [...] "; // Can't help you with your query as I don't know your DB structure
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$resultsArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $resultArray = array('CaseID' => $row['CaseID'], 'dbUser' => $row['dbUser']);
    $resultsArray[] = $resultArray;
}

?>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Case ID</th>
            <th>Sales User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($resultsArray as $resultArray) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $resultArray['CaseID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $resultArray['dbUser']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Would the SalesUser be in a seperate foreach down the bottom and also would I need to name the array something else for the SalesUser?

Comment: I'd recommend getting both `caseID` and `SalesUser` in the same request, and storing them both in the same array.

Comment: Without pushing the limit... Could you show me how this is done please? Still fairly new with arrays

Comment: Thank you! Going to test it out now... I'll let you know once it's done :)

Comment: So it's throwing an error. I have removed the SalesUser for now as it isn't 100% important, but say if I were to add in something else for it to call from the same table in the DB, I guess this would be done like this:


$resultArray = array('CaseID' => $row['CaseID'], 'Provider' => $row['Provider'],


Is this right? @roberto06

Comment: Yep, just don't forget to close your parenthesis.

Comment: Ignore me... I'm a complete idiot and forgot a semi-colon after $resultsArray[] = $resultArray

OOPS!

Thank you very much for your assistance @roberto06

Comment: Please update your question with the updated code, so that it'll be easier for us to see exactly what you're working with now.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may run into this, @roberto06 kindly assisted and it has now been fixed and is working.

```
$query = "SELECT CaseID, Provider, FROM Cases WHERE ClientID='".$_GET['ClientID']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$resultsArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $resultArray = array('CaseID' => $row['CaseID'], 'Provider' => $row['Provider'] );
    $resultsArray[] = $resultArray;
}

?>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Case ID</th>
            <th>Provider</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($resultsArray as $resultArray) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $resultArray['CaseID']; ?></td>
            <td><? echo $resultArray['Provider']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```